# Sql server 2017 install error 16389

Tags: installation, sql-server-2017

I keep getting the error for sql server 2017 install. Don't know how to solve

```
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Error result: -2147467259
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Result facility code: 0
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Result error code: 16389
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: WER: Application level consent value 'True' was mapped to consent status 'WerConsentApproved'
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: WER: Result of the submission:: 'WerReportQueued'
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: WER: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Closing Telemetry Session
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQMClient
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value MachineId
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Not creating telemetry audit log. Value 'UserRequestedLocalAuditDirectory' doesn't exist in 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140'
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SQL
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value SQLEXPRESS02
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS02\CPE
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value CustomerFeedback
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value EnableErrorReporting
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey OLAP
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey RS
(01) 2018-02-15 19:46:58 Slp: SetupTelemetry: Telemetry has an active session with 47 events.
```

Comment: Open you `RegEdit` as Administrator, Navigate to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\140` and create a folder there with the name `UserRequestedLocalAuditDirectory`, re-run the installer and see if it helps.

Comment: There is no option to create a folder. There are only key and some other things.

Comment: created the UserRequestedLocalAuditDirectory but it did not help